# Grunt usemin not replacing file references in sub directories or in compiled CSS file

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm finding the grunt-usemin tasks a little confusing to set up. I'm using grunt-usemin to concatenate, uglify and rev my files. It is working for the root index.html file, however, files in other directories are not getting replaced with the revved file reference.

I have the following file structure:

```
app
  index.html

  subfolderA
  --index.html

  subfolderB
  --index.html

  assets
  --img
  --js
  ----script.js
  --scss
  ----style.scss
```

On build, everything gets built into `/dist` directory.

My Gruntfile contains (among other tasks) the following:

```
useminPrepare: {
    options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    },
    html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**.html',
    css: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/scss/**.scss'
}

usemin: {
    options: {
       dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
    },
    html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**.html',
    css: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/css/style.css'
}

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'jekyll:dist',
    'spriteHD',
    'compassMultiple:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'copy:dist',
    'svgmin',
    'imagemin:dist',
    'svg2png',
    'modernizr',
    'concurrent:replacementsDist',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Blocks to be replaced in the HTML files look like:

```
<!-- build:js /assets/js/lteie8.main.js -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bower_components/selectivizr/selectivizr.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bower_components/respond/dest/respond.src.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Once built, `dist/index.html` shows all the correctly revved file names - for css, js concat blocks and all images. However, the compiled CSS file does not contain the revved file references. Nor in all subdirectory index.html files do the file references get updated to the revved versions.

With me referencing the HTML files with `**.html` I thought that should target all html files in subdirectories. I presume I have some mistake in the usemin or useminPrepare task, is this the case?

== EDIT ==

In response to przno's answer I changed `usemin:css:` to `<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/css/*.css` to get it to compile the CSS correctly.

Answer (score 0):

*With me referencing the HTML files with `**.html` I thought that should target all html files in subdirectories* - use `**/*.html`

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed the CSS sheet, meaning all the img references within the compiled CSS are now the revved versions, however, still in the HTML files, apart from the root index, they still refer to non-revved assets. Is there something else missing from the Usemin tasks?